# Display two integers in one column

Tags: sql-server, geospatial

I have silly problem. I Have table with `geometry` point information and I would like to select coordinates `X` and `Y` in one column. Result of `query 1`

```
select point.STY ,  point.STX from vertex where id =20
```

is:

```
 1 |158 |   361
```

However when I try to make it like:

```
select point.STY + ' ' +  point.STX from vertex where id =20
```

I get summarize of `158+361` as int:

```
1 | 519
```

and the result I wan to get is:

```
1 | 158 361
```

can anyone give me a hint what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

They're numeric fields, so the database presumes you want to add them mathematically. Force it to treat them as VARCHAR text fields, by using the CAST command to turn one data type into another, and it'll do as you require:

```
SELECT CAST(point.STY AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST(point.STX AS VARCHAR)
FROM vertex
WHERE id = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to CAST the INT values as VARCHAR:

```
select CAST(point.STY AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST(point.STX AS VARCHAR)
from vertex
where id =20
```